# Bulk processing data through a join with kafka-streams results in `Skipping record for expired segment`

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

When pushing bulk data through a kafka-steams app, I see it log the following message many times...

`WARN org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.AbstractRocksDBSegmentedBytesStore - Skipping record for expired segment.`

...and data which I expect to have been joined through a leftJoin step appears to be lost.

I've seen this in practice either when my application has been shut down for a while and then is brought back up, or when I've used something like the [app-reset-tool](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/app-reset-tool.html) in an attempt to have the application reprocess past data.

I was able to reproduce this behaviour in isolation by generating 1000 messages to two topics spaced an hour apart (with the original timestamps in order), then having kafka streams select a key for them and try to leftJoin the two rekeyed streams.

Self contained source code for that reproduction is available at https://github.com/mattsheppard/ins14809/blob/main/src/test/java/ins14809/Ins14809Test.java

The actual kafka-streams topology in there looks like this.

```
            final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
            final KStream<String, String> leftStream = builder.stream(leftTopic);
            final KStream<String, String> rightStream = builder.stream(rightTopic);

            final KStream<String, String> rekeyedLeftStream = leftStream
                    .selectKey((k, v) -> v.substring(0, v.indexOf(":")));

            final KStream<String, String> rekeyedRightStream = rightStream
                    .selectKey((k, v) -> v.substring(0, v.indexOf(":")));

            JoinWindows joinWindow = JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(5));

            final KStream<String, String> joined = rekeyedLeftStream.leftJoin(
                    rekeyedRightStream,
                    (left, right) -> left + "/" + right,
                    joinWindow
            );
```

...and the eventual output I produce looks like this...

```
...
523 [523,left/null]
524 [524,left/null, 524,left/524,right]
525 [525,left/525,right]
526 [526,left/null]
527 [527,left/null]
528 [528,left/528,right]
529 [529,left/null]
530 [530,left/null]
531 [531,left/null, 531,left/531,right]
532 [532,left/null]
533 [533,left/null]
534 [534,left/null, 534,left/534,right]
535 [535,left/null]
536 [536,left/null]
537 [537,left/null, 537,left/537,right]
538 [538,left/null]
539 [539,left/null]
540 [540,left/null]
541 [541,left/null]
542 [542,left/null]
543 [543,left/null]
...
```

...where as, given the input data, I expect to see every row end with the two values joined, rather than the right value being null.

(Note that it's fine/expected that we initially get the left/null values for each value - That's the expected semantics of kafka-streams left join as I understand it.)

I've noticed that if I set a very large grace value on the join window the problem is solved, but since the input I provide is not out of order I did not expect to need to do that, and I'm weary of the resource requirements doing so in practice on an application with a lot of volume.

My suspicion is that something is happening such that when one partition is processed it causes the stream time to be pushed forward to the newest message in that partition, meaning when the next partition is then examined it is found to contain many records which are 'too old' compared to the stream time. I'm hoping, however, that someone can point me towards a setting to change that behaviour, or some other solution which avoids producing inaccurate results whenever the application is catching up through a backlog of data without imposing a big performance overhead.

Comment: your suspicion is correct but it seems to be just normal behaviour of JoinWindows if I understood your issue correctly, i posted more detailed answer about it.

Comment: Raised this as https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-13289 since it seems to be an underlying issue in kafka-streams itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are publish messages spaces 1 hour apparent and then it fails to join?
Right now you are using:

```
JoinWindows joinWindow = JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
```

changing that to higher number or adding grace period will allow you to handle many more messages, wiht messages being 1 hour apart and you having 1000 messages, so value of:

```
JoinWindows joinWindow = JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).grace(Duration.ofDays(42));
```

Is needed. (as 1000 * 5h is near 42 days)
So you need to adjust this value to size of your data to always be able to perform this operation on all messages you expect.

Then i get results that you expect... I think so. As im not enteirly sure about other nulls here, but you seems to says its expected - didn't analyse that part. As some entires do have it, others don't.

```
 11 [11:left/null, 11:left/11:right]
 12 [12:left/12:right]
 13 [13:left/null, 13:left/13:right]
 14 [14:left/null, 14:left/14:right]
 15 [15:left/null, 15:left/15:right]
 16 [16:left/null, 16:left/16:right]
 17 [17:left/17:right]
 18 [18:left/null, 18:left/18:right]
 19 [19:left/null, 19:left/19:right]
 20 [20:left/null, 20:left/20:right]
 21 [21:left/null, 21:left/21:right]
 22 [22:left/null, 22:left/22:right]
 23 [23:left/null, 23:left/23:right]
 24 [24:left/null, 24:left/24:right]
 25 [25:left/25:right]
 26 [26:left/null, 26:left/26:right]
```

But there is always valid pair preset for all 1000 results.

You want the older data so you must agree for older data.

> but as I understand it having a very large grace period would be costly

Probably it would be costly, if your grace period will be much bigger than what you need, but in this case its exacly what you need. Unless you can just avoid doing that join altogether.
As you can see in documentation the grace does exacly what you want (or rather what you don't want, with its default low value):
https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/JoinWindows.html#grace-java.time.Duration-

> Reject late events that arrive more than afterWindowEnd after the end of its window. Lateness is defined as (stream_time - record_timestamp).

Altenative soultion is to use bigger window, but this does not look like correct solution for your case:

```
JoinWindows joinWindow = JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofDays(42);
```

Comment: Thanks - I guess I'm looking for a solution which isn't 'set a massive join/grace window', but rather takes advantage of the input being in order, since the app is high volume and mostly runs in a continual streaming mode.

I've been thinking that, if I can programatically get the lag of intermediate topics somehow, perhaps I can have something which trickles the input in at a rate which the app can reliably process without a huge window.

Comment: @MattSheppard that sounds a bit like pre-optimisation, are you sure you need something else? You just have very spaced data, usually its many events per minute, not 1 per hour, so having join window of 40 days with 20 events for minuite for sure would be heavy. But here? I would just use it and measure if there are any issues. And then i would also go with different question on stack, about different way to process the data, not to fix the join.

Comment: In practice my app has thousands of events per second, and this same issue crops up if I shut the app down for an hour and then turn it back on again as it tries to catch up - the example here is just to expose the issue I see in a simple way without the rest of the apps complexity. Having a grace window as big as the longest possible app outage isn’t practical I’m afraid. But it sounds like the real answer is just that Kafka-streams isn’t actually fit for my purpose currently. Pity, but ok.

Comment: @MattSheppard Not sure if there is better solution from kafka, But for sure having fallback instance or just something to increase the grace period only when app starts to cover the missed parts